# AWS policy to allow access only to a specific bucket folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM policy to allow a user access only to a specific folder in an S3 bucket.
How do I do this using visual policy editor?
In the resource section if I mention the arn for the folder, the user is being denied access to the whole bucket.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a policy that grants access to a specific folder within a bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["folder1/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/folder1/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Things to note:

- The `ListBucket` operation that allows *listing* a bucket is a permission on the *bucket itself* (not a path). To restrict which folders they can list, the folder must be specified via the `s3:prefix`.
- The `GetObject` and `PutObject` operations operate on *objects*, so the folder can be referenced in the ARN.

It is also possible to use [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) to refer to a username. This policy can be applied to an **IAM Group** and will allow each user access to a folder with their own name:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, how is this done using the web console ? I am just trying to understand.

Comment: This policy can be added as an **inline policy** in the console. This means it is a one-off policy only applied to one IAM User or IAM Group, as opposed to being a Managed Policy (which is version-tracked and frequently reused). You can create the policy using the "Visual editor", but I normally copy an existing policy and make modifications. For that, I click the "JSON" tab and paste the policy as a whole. Frankly, I am more comfortable reading the JSON policy and I only use the Visual editor when I am creating a totally new policy.